# How to update breeze.js library

Tags: breeze

I could use some guidance on how to manually update between versions of Breeze and it's dependencies.  I do not believe I can just update with the NuGet Package Manager.

I have been developing my Single Page App with Breeze, Knockout, WebAPI and so forth.  I have been using Breeze version 0.61 and want to upgrade to the latest version so I can take advantage of the ODataActionFilters and not have to parse the Request.QueryString to pull out parameters and filters.  For example when I call

```
       var getMachineById(machineId) {
            var query = EntityQuery
            .from("Machines")
            .where("machineId", "eq", machineId);

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (data) {
                do_something_with(data.results);
            })
            .fail(queryFailed);
       }
```

There has to be a way for Breeze to handle that for me, so I can just do something like this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IQueryable<Machine> Machines()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Machines;
    }
```

instead of

```
    // eg "?$filter=machineId%20eq%205"
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IQueryable<Machine> Machines()
    {
        IQueryable<Machine> x = _contextProvider.Context.Machines;
        List<ODataQueryString> list = null;
        string qs = Request.RequestUri.Query.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);  
        list = new ODataQueryStringParser(qs).Parse();
        if (list != null)
        {
            int machineId = int.Parse(list[0].Value); // covert string to an int
            x = x.Where(o => o.MachineId == machineId);
        }

        return x;
    }
```

1. I notice that the Attribute decoration in the Controller has changed in the Samples.  Do I need to change mine too?

   ```
   namespace PilotPlantBreeze.Controllers
   {
       [JsonFormatter, ODataActionFilter]
       public class BreezeController : ApiController
       {
           readonly EFContextProvider<PilotPlantDbContext> _contextProvider =
           new EFContextProvider<PilotPlantDbContext>();

           [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
           public string Metadata()
           {
               return _contextProvider.Metadata();
           }
           [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
           public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
           {
               return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
           }
    ... etc.
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have my 3rd party libraries in a folder ~\Scripts\lib.  If I use the NuGet package manager to update, it puts all the replacements in ~\Scripts.  How do I move the files into the lib folder without messing up my Team Foundation Server (Azure) source control?
3. Are the runtime versions of Antlr3.Runtime.dll, Breeze.WebApi.dll, Irony.dll, Newtonsoft.Json.dll, WebActivator.dll and maybe WebGrease.dll compatible between versions.  I bet not.  Is there something I have to change in Visual Studio?
4. Can I just change version entries from the package folder in packages.config?

   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best approach would be to remove any existing breeze '.js' files and the webApi and irony.dlls from your project and then simply install the latest breeze nuget package. After installing the nuget package you can go ahead and move the files to other locations within the project to match their "old" locations.  I'd do the same for the NewtonSoft nuget package as well, just in case ( breeze will add this back for you). Going forward, you can just update to latest nuget and then move the files.

As you noticed you will also need to replace these attributes

[JsonFormatter, ODataActionFilter]

with this attribute

[BreezeController]

This assumes that you are not running a beta version of ASP.MVC4.  I think there are posts in other forums that discuss how to  migrate away from the beta.